# DNS on my VPS does not forward mail to Godaddy

Tags: dns

I have a client that has a domain and email plan with Godaddy. I host their website on my VPS elsewhere. If I send them an email from my VPS, like a PHP contact form on their website or my business email, it does not send to their Godaddy account but instead tries to deliver locally. I found this out after a few days of contact form emails, which use PHPmailer using SMTP settings from the VPS, not showing up in their Godaddy account. I went into cpanel on my VPS and added the same email account and it started receiving the emails. The Godaddy DNS records look like this (the A Record value is the IP of my VPS):

[image: Godaddy DNS Records]

At my VPS cpanel I updated the MX record to what you see below...

[image: IO Zoome DNS]

I updated this MX record over 7 hours ago and the TTL is only 4 hours but I am still not seeing emails make it through to their Godaddy mailbox if I am sending using my VPS emails. Is this the correct record to send all mail on to Godaddy – smtp.secureserver.net?

---

### UPDATE 1/28/18

Leaving a note to clarify the issue for future readers. My final question would have been better worded "Is an MX record all that is needed to ensure locally originating email gets routed to a remote mail server?"

Also, I did not make it clear that emails sent to the domain would deliver as expected to Godaddy from any other service, such as Gmail etc. This problem was only experienced when I sent emails from my VPS email accounts.

Comment: Did you start by asking GoDaddy what is the record to use?

Comment: It's not a Godaddy issue, so it would not be appropriate to ask them. The problem resides with the records on my VPS. As I said the problem only occurs when I send an email originating from my VPS. If I send from Gmail or anywhere else it delivers correctly to Godaddy. Yes I have been communicating with my VPS host tech support but they are not being very helpful... offshore support that is giving me canned answers.

Comment: You have the MX record correct for Godaddy but If your domain is hosted at Godaddy then Godaddy is where the MX records would be (and they are) but you're using an MX record locally, too. Can you configure email sending on your VPS to look to the authoritative name server when sending email? Does the documentation say to configure a local MX record even when the zone file for the domain is hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Your question is: " Is this the correct record to send all mail on to Godaddy – smtp.secureserver.net?"  so clearly a GoDaddy issue, you need to ask them what value you need to use. If this is not your question then please edit and rephrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future. I was working in cPanel but if you go to WHM and choose DNS Functions > Edit DNS Zones and then the domain you're working with at the very bottom of the page, below all of the records is a set of radio buttons for "Email Routing" where you can choose "Remote Email Exchanger." This fixed my problem.

[image]